# How to handle errors in angular?

Tags: angularjs

In a few controllers I have the following:

```
CategoryService.GetCategoryList()
  .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.categories = data.Categories;
  })
  .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { });
```

How should I handle errors in angular?

Is there a way to centralize the error handling?

Comment: You can use a custom service to handle errors

Comment: So I would inject that service into my controllers? And should I log the errors on a database calling an API or just console.log? What is usually done?

Comment: @Miguel -- Well typically your server-side method would already handle logging the error. You can use a centralized error service to display error messages / direct the user to a better path.

Comment: @tymeJV ... Yes, that is right. The server side takes care of that.

Comment: In our project we created a custom service which populates ui-bootstrap alerts http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/alert

Comment: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-catching-errors-with-exceptionhandler